# Having trouble understanding the logical structure of this statement

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, and let $K = \{x \in G: xax^{-1} \in H \iff a \in H\}$.

Does this mean that $K$ is all of $G$?  The statement seems to say nothing about $x$ itself.  If there is no $a \in H$ that $x$ conjugates, then the antecedent is false so that statement is trivially true.

Comment: I think this is a 'standard' interpretation of logical symbols: the test "$xax^{-1}\in H\Leftrightarrow a\in H$" has an implicit universal quantifier tying the free variable $a$ to its largest natural scope (here the bigger group $G$). So $x$ is in the set $K$, if and only if for all elements $a\in G$, $a$ is in $H$ exactly when $xax^{-1}$ is. IOW
$$\forall\,a\in G: xax^{-1}\in H\leftrightarrow a\in H.$$
After all, the membership test must be a predicate that has a defined value for a given 'candidate element' $x$. For that reason it is necessary to use the universal quantifier to close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement $xax^{-1} \in H \Longleftrightarrow a \in H$ for all $a \in H$ is logically equivalent to the equality of sets $xHx^{-1} = H$.  That might help you understand $K$ better.

For an example where $K \neq G$, let $G = S_3$ (the group of permutations of a set with $3$ elements) and $H = \{e, (1,2)\}$ (the subgroup consisting of the identity permutation and the permutation interchanging $1$ and $2$).  To see this, consider the permutation $x = (1,3)$ (interchanging $2$ and $3$).  Then $xHx^{-1} = \{e, (2,3)\} \neq H$, so $x \notin K$.  As an exercise, you should compute $K$ for this example.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will help.  I need to think about this.

Comment: Okay, I just realized that $H$ is already determined!  I was thinking that $H$ was being defined at the same time as $K$, and that was really confusing.

Comment: Glad it is making more sense to you!  The subgroup $K$ is called the normalizer of $H$ in $G$.  It is the largest subgroup of $G$ in which $H$ is normal.  That means: if $K' \subseteq G$ is any subgroup of $G$ which has the property that it contains $H$ as a normal subgroup, then $K'$ is a subgroup of $K$.  You'll often see the notation $N_G(H)$ or just $N(H)$ for the normalizer of $H$ in $G$, instead of $K$.

Answer (score 2):

"If there is no $a \in H$ that $x$ conjugates" makes no sense. You can use $x$ to conjugate any element $a$; the question is what the result will be, and the statement says that $K$ contains the elements $x$ of $G$ such that conjugating $a$ with $x$ yields an element of $H$ iff $a$ is in $H$.

Answer (score 1):

$$xax^{-1} \in H \iff a \in H$$

means that if $a$ is in $H$, then $xax^{-1}$ is in $H$, and if $a$ is an element of $G$ such that $xax^{-1}$ is in $H$, then $a$ is also in $H$.  So $x$ is in $K$ if the above happens.  To contrast, $x$ is *not* in $K$ if there exists $a\in H$ such that $xax^{-1}$ is not in $H$, or if there exists $a\in G\setminus H$ such that $xax^{-1}$ is in $H$.

Comment: But if $xax^{-1}$ is not in $H$, doesn't that mean that $a$ would not be in $H$?

Comment: @Matt: If $x$ is in $K$, then yes that would be implied by definition of $K$.  But not in general; that is why the definition of $K$ gives you a condition that $x$ must satisfy to be in $K$.  If you are familiar with normal subgroups, consider the following.  If $H$ is not a normal subgroup, then there exists $a\in H$ and $x\in G$ such that $xax^{-1}$ is not in $H$.  In that case, $x$ is not an element of $K$.  On the other hand, if $H$ is a normal subgroup, then $K=G$.